# How to maintain connection between the activity and background service when change orientation

Tags: android, service, connection, orientation

My app just has one activity and one service which keeps checking the location. There is one button to start the service and connect to the service. Press the button again to stop the service. The activity bind to the service and retrieve the location every 10s.
The problem is, after the service is started, and change the orientation, then stop the service, the app crashed. Anyone can advise how to maintain the "connection" in such case?

```
    private TrackLocationService tracker;
    private boolean bBound = false;
    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            TrackLocationService.TrackerBinder trackerBinder = (TrackLocationService.TrackerBinder)service;
            tracker = trackerBinder.getTracker();
            bBound = true;

            Log.i(TAG, "onServiceConnected: " + connection.toString()); ///...MapsActivity$1@d4a143a
            iState = 2;
            ShowButtons();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            //bBound = false;
            tracker = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");//never reached, why?
        }
    };

    public void OnClickStartButton(View view)
    {
        if (iState > 1)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "onClickStopButton: "+ connection.toString()); //can see the connection value changed: ...MapsActivity$1@8473fd6
            
            if (!connection.equals( null) ){
                unbindService(connection); ///this crashed the app after change orientation, why?
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "onClickStopButton1");

            bBound = false;
            iState = 0;
            ShowButtons();
            Log.i(TAG, "onClickStopButton2");
            //reset target
            targetLocation=null;

            if (mMarker != null) mMarker.remove();
            //remove the circle
            if (circle != null)circle.remove();
            circle = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "onClickStopButton3");
        }
        else
        {
            if (targetLocation == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set target location first", LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onClickStartButton");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackLocationService.class);
                intent.putExtra("TARGET_LOCATION", targetLocation);
                startService(intent);
                bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);//to get the data from service
                AddNotification();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonRangeDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRangeDown);
        buttonRangeUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRangeUp);
        buttonIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIn);
        buttonOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOut);
        tvHelp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHelp);
        //restore the values
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate loading bundle");

            targetLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("LOCATION");
            iAlarmMode = savedInstanceState.getInt("ALARM");
            iRangeSet = savedInstanceState.getInt("RANGE");
            //connection = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("CONNECTION");
            iState = savedInstanceState.getInt("ISTATE");
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate loaded bundle");
        }
        ShowButtons();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate iAlarmMode "+ iAlarmMode);
        fusedLocationClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        
        fetchLastLocation();
        monitorDistance();
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);

        bundle.putInt("ALARM", iAlarmMode);
        bundle.putInt("RANGE", iRangeSet);
        bundle.putInt("ISTATE", iState);
        bundle.putParcelable("LOCATION", targetLocation);
        //bundle.putParcelable("CONNECTION", (Parcelable) connection);//possible to save the connection?

        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");

        ShowButtons();
    }
```

Comment: Create a singleton of `ServiceConnection` and use it to start/stop/bind/unbind service.

Comment: Thanks Jenea, do you mean that pull the ServiceConnection outside of Activity class to be a separated class as a global variable so remain in the memory and be independent from orientation change? It is a good idea to try.

Comment: But is there any method to save in the bundle and restore from onCreate for such non-standard variables?

Comment: "do you mean that pull the ServiceConnection outside of Activity class to be a separated class as a global variable" - yes, exactly.
"to save in the bundle and restore from onCreate" - you cannot save in Bundle an active running service. When you saving something into a Bundle it is parsed into bits and stored as passive information. In other words, what is in Bundle or serialized does not run and is not active.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu: trying to do the singleton, and found that need to update the Activity onServiceConnected, should I have to use some mechanism like broadcast message/receive message for that? Or there are other simpler method? Cannot post the new class 'public class TrackerServiceConnection' here. If use "Answer your question" to post the codes, will this question be closed and cannot answer/comment again?